# Is Bluetooth (headphones) efficient for gaming?

Tags: hardware, audio-hardware

I read that Bluetooth on several headphones send the sound with a small delay. This is not a problem when you listen to music or talking with a friend but it is a problem when watching a movie or playing a game.

Could you confirm this delay? Is this delay a problem of Bluetooth in general or only old version of Bluetooth and has been fixed with 3.0 or 4.0 version or is only related to specific brand or i don't know?

(This questions stand in the Game-specific hardware and utilities category)

Comment: There's always at least some delay when using external (but even internal) hardware, even if it's just the delay the signal needs to get through A/D and D/A converters and the cable. The question is, how susceptible you are to it and how long it really is.

Comment: I'm not sure bluetooth headphones fall into gaming specific hardware.

Comment: Bluetooth is worse than most other audio hardware because it requires compression, which requires at least some buffering. The fact that it uses noisy radio spectrum as its medium makes it worse. There's going to be lost packets, which either means audio dropouts or more buffering.

Comment: One final problem with traditional "bluetooth audio" headsets not yet mentioned is that when there's a brief connection glitch, the sound can get roughly half a second out of sync with the image, and will never really sync back. For movies you can at least pause and resume to fix it, but in a game you'd probably be completely stuffed.

Answer (score 6):

Searching around, they should be fine if you get some specific things. Mainly, it means getting [aptx codec](http://www.aptx.com/howitworks2), preferably a headset with the latest bluetooth version (4.2 right now if I'm not mistaken) or that provide low latency and a adapter/dongle that has low latency (< 32 ms).

From to this [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/21lsq5/stay_away_from_bluetooth_headphones/):

> you need APT-X to get rid of latency over bluetooth, otherwise it's completely unacceptable for absolutely everything imaginable

and

> What you need is a BT 4.0 with low latency headset and a matching transmitter with also low latency feature. BT chip behave this way for the extra feature(APTX and Latency) to work both the receiver and transmitter must have the feature.

Here's a good [article on bluetooth headset](http://theheadphonelist.com/wireless-fidelity-making-sense-bluetooth-headphone-technology/)